# How to create an interceptor that deletes old record (LIFO) on insert after reaching predefined record limit?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

***Hibernate Question***

I would like to ensure a maximum of X records per each UID(non unique).

When reaching the limit, I want hibernate to delete the "last in" record before/after inserting the new one.

Table example:
**Messages**

```
UID| ID | MESSAGE
YY    1       "1"
YY    2       "2"
```

e.g: For a limit of 2 messages for UID, a new message "3" will remove message "1" so the table ends up with 2 messages for same "YY" UID.

Expected result:

```
UID| ID | MESSAGE
YY    2       "2"
YY    3       "3"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `PostPersist` [JPA Entity Listener in hibernate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks) that acts upon persisting an instance of your entity. The entity listener then queries and removes instances that exceed the limits.

Since you tagged `spring-data-jpa` you could also use a `TransactionalEventListener` in spring (see [transaction bound events](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html#transaction-event)) in phase `BEFORE_COMMIT` that does the same thing as the entity listener.

The difference is that the transactional event listener will only be invoked once per transaction where in contrast the entity listener could be invoked many times depending on the number of instances you persist per transaction.

Comment: I understand OP asked for Hibernate based solution, but how would this compare to standard db triggers?

Comment: I know this solution, but I didn't find a way to run queries on the inserted row, like deleting old record by new record UID.
Also, it seems like this method is used for entity manipulation and not table manipulation from what I see in the documentation.

Comment: From the JPA Spec (2.2) "In general, the lifecycle method of a portable application should not invoke EntityManager or query operations, access other entity instances, or modify relationships within the
same persistence context . A lifecycle callback method may modify the non-relationship state of the entity on which it is invoked."

Comment: @Leet-Falcon When you use JPA you better don't want the database to change it's state without the JPA entity manager knowing about that. For example if a trigger would delete some rows and the JPA entity manager thinks that that these rows are still persistent, there might be problems when the entity manager state is later flushed to the database.